# How to talk about style

Tags: word-choice

"日本で流行はおもしろいですね。流行は日本の方がアメリカよりだいじとおもいます。たくさんの種類です。好きな服装はなんですか？"

In this case am I using "服装" correctly? I'm trying to express that I think that fashion is more important in Japan and asking what the person's favorite style is.

There are other words for "style" such as 様式. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I think 好きな服装は何ですか? and 好きな服はなんですか? are correct and 好きなファッションは何ですか? is also ordinary used but 様式 isn't used in fashion.

I think 様式 is formal. A dictionary say http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/226436/meaning/m0u/

In addition, スタイル means mainly "a shape of a body" in Japan.

Comment: What about 流行? It's classified as "common" leading me to believe that you could use it as well:

http://jisho.org/search/fashion

I think that 様式 might have to do with writing style, or a pattern such as on a piece of fabric or on a building, also a pattern of organization (of something in general).

I guess 服装 would have to do solely with style of clothing.

Comment: @PaulCunningham 流行 is a fashion as in a craze or fad (like your dictionary link says). Something that's "in" fashion. It's not limited to clothes. 世間に広く行われ、用いられること。**服装・言葉・思想など、ある様式や風俗**が一時的にもてはやされ、世間に広まること。http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/231934/meaning/m1u/%E6%B5%81%E8%A1%8C/

Comment: If you want to accent 流行, you say "好きな流行りの服(or  ファッション)はなんですか?" but pay attention for the reading. The reading is "はやり".

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about Hayari. What a difficult distinction, especially with 様式. Thanks for helping me talk through the words and meanings, it helps remember.